# How to make a menu like the following Image

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]
Please help me with this. Is there any library for this? Thanks in advance

**I want the method and ingredients buttons and it should be swipe able**

**I want the method and ingredients buttons and it should be swipe able**

Answer (score 0):

Try react-native-tab-view - https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view

or

react-native-swipe-tabs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-tabs

Comment: I want the ingredients and method buttons

Comment: you have to communicate clearly with your question or the image itself can be annotated.

Comment: Not working as expected